# Why typescript with strictNullChecks=true doesn't complain when accessing the property of an object?

Tags: typescript, strictnullchecks

Probably there is something I don't understand. In this code I expect typescript to emit a warning for the line `page.name = 'foo';` because `page` can be null?

```
export interface Page {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

const pages: { [id: string]: Page } = {};

function f(id: string) {
  let page = pages[id];
  page.name = 'foo';
}
```

Can someone explain me? Thanks!

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgBUwHM8BvAKDkQBMAuOAZximSIG5K4lMBbYepiyTtyAX3LlsEJEzhhiwBvVJwA2gjqNmrALr1CJOKLgBeOKVEdy6AK5JsMBNLjoAFBoHbhASnOcANsDw8oZmIYrq1DocVOEAdNx8pnAA5OgQECkc4tauKdLAKd5sQA)

Comment: You probably want `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKVVzm)

Comment: thanks for your help :-)